# jQuery UI dialog position in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

In IE7, my jQuery-UI dialog openers seem to be setting focus to the (invisible) position of the dialog, which is at the end of the `<body>`. Other browsers maintain focus where it is so you can read the dialog, which is centered in the viewport. So the effect is that in IE7/8 the page scrolls to the bottom, past the dialog, when the opener is clicked.

I think I have all the relevant bits included here.

Using: jQuery v1.4.2, jQuery-UI 1.8.17, no theme

UPDATE [Here is a a working example.](http://donzacharias.com/tests2.htm) This has basically everything involved in getting my page to where it's at now. Everything seems to work in Firefox, Chrome and IE8 but IE7 is still not behaving. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example page we can see that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I'm working on it... Trying to put the relevant parts in a JSFiddle doesn't reproduce the behavior :) This appears to work fine in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/MHtRF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I was not using a Theme. I just needed a simple skin, so I thought I'd just add some rules to my existing CSS instead of adding the overhead of a whole theme, but that doesn't work for